# No consigo que se vea lo seleccionado en un CheckboxListTile dentro de un AlertDialog

Tags: flutter

estoy intentando poner un CheckboxListTile dentro de un AlertDialog, y funciona bien, pero cuando selecciono algunos de los checkbox quiero que su texto lo ponga donde lo he llamado. Este es el códogo:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(PadelApp());
}

class PadelApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, //esto es para quitar el cartelito de debug
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData( primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  //@override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>{

  var _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var _lstgrupos = ['Group 1', 'Group 2'];
  List<String> _SelectedGroupsItems = [];
  String _SelectedGroups="Grupos";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test')),

      body: Form(
        key: _formkey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(_SelectedGroups),
                      onTap: () => showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        barrierDismissible: true,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return StatefulBuilder(
                            builder: (context,setState) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: Text("Choose a group"),
                                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      children: _lstgrupos.map((lst) => CheckboxListTile(
                                            title: Text(lst),
                                            value: _SelectedGroupsItems.contains(lst),
                                            onChanged: (value) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                if (value!) {
                                                  if (!_SelectedGroupsItems.contains(lst)) {
                                                    _SelectedGroupsItems.add(lst);
                                                  }
                                                } else {
                                                  if (_SelectedGroupsItems.contains(lst)) {
                                                    _SelectedGroupsItems.remove(lst);
                                                  }
                                                }
                                                _SelectedGroups=_SelectedGroupsItems.join(", ");
                                                print(_SelectedGroups);
                                              });
                                            },
                                          )).toList(),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  TextButton(
                                    child: Text('Cerrar'),
                                    onPressed: ()=> Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                                  )
                                ]
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        }
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Me explico de nuevo, cuando pico donde pone "Grupos" (es el title del ListTile), se va a la lista de checkbox y al seleccionar uno o lo dos, quiero que donde antes ponía Grupos, ahora ponga los nombres de los grupos elegidos separados por coma. En la variable _SelectedGroups va esa cadena, pero no se actualiza cuando se cierra el AlertDialog. ¿Por qué?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesita utilizar una función 'callback'. Separa Statefulbuilder en una nueva clase y pásalo 'callback'. En onChanged se ejecuta 'callback' a actualizar variables y setstate en pantalla padre.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(PadelApp());
}

class PadelApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, //esto es para quitar el cartelito de debug
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  //@override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _lstgrupos = ['Group 1', 'Group 2'];
  List<String> _SelectedGroupsItems = [];
  String _SelectedGroups = "Grupos";

  void callback( _SelectedGroupsItems, _SelectedGroups) {
    this._SelectedGroupsItems = _SelectedGroupsItems;
    this._SelectedGroups = _SelectedGroups;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test')),
      body: Form(
        key: _formkey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(_SelectedGroups),
                      onTap: () => showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          barrierDismissible: true,
                          builder: (context) {
                            return MyDialog(callback, _SelectedGroupsItems, _SelectedGroups).build();
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDialog {
  Function callback;
  var _lstgrupos = ['Group 1', 'Group 2'];
  List<String> _SelectedGroupsItems = [];
  String _SelectedGroups = "Grupos";

  MyDialog(this.callback, this._SelectedGroupsItems, this._SelectedGroups);

  Widget build() {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Choose a group"),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: _lstgrupos
                      .map((lst) => CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Text(lst),
                            value: _SelectedGroupsItems.contains(lst),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                if (value!) {
                                  if (!_SelectedGroupsItems.contains(lst)) {
                                    _SelectedGroupsItems.add(lst);
                                  }
                                } else {
                                  if (_SelectedGroupsItems.contains(lst)) {
                                    _SelectedGroupsItems.remove(lst);
                                  }
                                }
                                _SelectedGroups = _SelectedGroupsItems.join(", ");
                                if (_SelectedGroups == ''){_SelectedGroups = 'Grupos';}
                                print(_SelectedGroups);
                                callback( _SelectedGroupsItems, _SelectedGroups);
                              });
                            },
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Cerrar'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              )
            ]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Perdona por no contestar antes pero no he podido meterle mano hasta ahora. Todo correcto, he probado el código y va. No sabía lo de los callback. Muchas gracias

Comment: Mi placer. Me gusta que el código funcionar ​bien.